# Load stop words from multiple text files in a directory

Tags: python

I have a directory with different text files of stop words. I want to import them all together, using `with open()`, but am getting an error:

```
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Directory", "*.txt"))

corpus = []

for file_path in file_list:

    with open(file_path,'r') as stop_words:
        stop_words.append(stop_words.read())
stopWords = stop_words.read().lower()
stopWordList = stopWords.split('\n')
stopWordList[-1:] = []
```

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

Thanks

Comment: Maybe stop_words.write?

Comment: not writable @funnydman

Comment: Oh, yes, because you opened the file for reading not writing

Comment: You open the file as `stop_words`, then you try to append the contents of `stop_words` to itself... Did you mean `corpus.append(...)`? What is the format of the text files? One word per line?

Comment: Yes..One word per line.  

ex - water
       Fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get all words into a list.

```py
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Directory", "*.txt"))

stopwords = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        stopwords.extend(f.read().lower().splitlines())
```

Comment: But I need all text in lower format......by using .lower() it is giving error

list' object has no attribute 'lower'

@fsimonjetz

Comment: See my edit. `lower` is a string method, you can't apply it to a list.